# Get Date based on day count in Dart

Tags: java, datetime, flutter, dart

I want to get this done in **Dart language** for Flutter framework. I'm very new for Dart. Bellow is the Java example of what I want to do. In brief, I want to get the date by passing a known year and day count of the year. Your help is highly appreciate.

```
Year year = Year.of( 2017 );
LocalDate localDate = year.atDay( 159 );
int dayOfYear = localDate.getDayOfYear() ;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add days to specified year starting from 1st of January :

```dart
DateTime year = DateTime(2017);
DateTime date = year.add(Duration(days: 159));
print(date);
```